# Get only first first occurence (if exists) in string with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have some troubles with a RegEx which don't do what I expect. Can someone tell me where I'm wrong ?

**Goal**: Get the first words (if exists) finishing with "'s " (with a space at the end)

RegEx :

```
".*'s "
```

Test string and the expected result :

```
Amarok's Golovin's Road => Amarok's 
Arkouna Dream's Elowin Engel's => Arkouna Dream's 
Arkouna Dream's Elowin Engel's => Arkouna Dream's  (in this case, I added a space after Engel's)
Liubov's Niagara => Liubov's 
Urane Of Watson Lake => nothing
```

**Problem**: When I have 2 occurences of "'s ", it returns a wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*'s(?!\S)
^\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{L}+)*'s(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bRD0rq/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `\p{L}*` - zero or more letters
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+)*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespace chars followed with one or more letters
- `'s` - an `'s` substring
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary.

Comment: words in this case are kennel names. it's just some samples. It could be anything else like "Of the mountain's Dog" => "Of the mountain's"

Comment: @NolmëInformatique Then let second+ words start with any letter, `^\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{L}+)*'s(?!\S)`